# How can I make each value go before each other with react-select

Tags: react-select

When you use react-select multi-select option, the default behavior is for each value once selected be inserted after each other.

you can see this behavior on the example site here for the MultiSelect option. https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

How can I insert each value component before, instead of after ?
Is there some sort of trick to do this ?

here is a code box.
https://codesandbox.io/s/y8RD0GVWg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to ordering the selected values lays in the function that handles the changes.

It concats each new selection, you can split it into an array and reverse it.

```
 handleSelectChange = value => {
     const data = value.split(',');

    const d = [
      data[data.length-1],
      ...data.slice(0, data.length - 1),
    ]

    console.log("You've selected:", value, data, d);

    this.setState({ value: d });
  };
```